# Azure AKS HPA failed to get cpu utilization

Tags: azure, kubernetes, autoscaling, azure-aks

I have a single node K8s cluster in Azure using AKS. I created a deployment and a service using a simple command:

`kubectl run php-apache --image=pilchard/hpa-example:latest --requests=cpu=200m,memory=300M --expose --port=80`

And enabled HPA via command:
`kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=10 --min=1 --max=15`

Upon running `kubectl describe hpa php-apache`, I see an error saying:

```
horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

And CPU metric is unknown upon running `kubectl get hpa`. Any help would be really appreciated.

My AKS kube version is `v1.9.11`.

Comment: i think you need heapster running on aks for this to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to install the [heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster)(Deprecated) or the [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) minimally to be able to use an [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

This provides the minimum set of CPU and Memory metrics to be able to autoscale. A good way to see if you have either installed is that if you get this kind output from `kubectl top pod`:

```
$ kubectl top pod
NAME                        CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
http-svc-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx   1m           7Mi
myapp-pod                   0m           53Mi
sleep-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx      4m           27Mi
```

Comment: I have installed the `metrics-server` on my cluster via `kubectl apply -f metrics-server/deploy/1.8+/` But still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: What do you see when you issue `kubectl top pod`?

Comment: I see only 'php-apache' pod

Comment: Do you see any metrics? or not

Comment: Nope. I'm still seeing the HPA status unknown. :(

Comment: What do you see in the logs of the 'metrics-server' pod

Comment: I can see the `metric-server` pod inside `kube-system` ns. Logs of the pod say:
`unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/php-apache-6b5fb79747-nxnq7: no metrics known for pod`

Comment: I tried with Kubernetes version `1.10.8` and it worked. Don't know what's wrong with newer versions on AKS.

Answer (score 0):

if you have metrics-server added (which comes as default with latest asks) do the following to fix it.

```
kubectl edit deployment applicationName
```

in the above cmd replace appliationName with name of your application and if you call youre deployment.yml deploy then replace that too and in the edit mode add the following after "terminationMessagePolicy" line.

```
              resource:
                 requests:
                   cpu: 50m
                 limits:
                   cpu: 500m
```

Once you have finished editing press "esc" key and type :wq your changes will be saved and after few seconds if you do

```
kubectl get hpa
```

or

```
kubectl describe hpa applicationName
```

you should not see any error,
please note to change the cpu limit and request based on your application usage they are only example values here